# As requested: how can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion

[Is dying in a simulation like dying?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70413/if-you-die-inside-a-simulation-then-do-we-die-outside-it)

How can I improve this question and get it reopened?

If  no-one can be bothered reopening the question then I'm just done, and won't be back: the site serves no purpose for me due to its vetting process / cabal.

Comment: As a biologist and avid player of video games if you take "die outside" to mean "biological death" and take "simulation" to apply broadly: *trivially no*. Otherwise I would have died thousands of times by now. If your question is to have some sort of non-trivial answer you need to define your parameters better.

Comment: thanks @BryanKrause !!

Comment: The question isn't redeemable. The technology of The Matrix doesn't exist, so there's no answer. If someone in the future invented the technology they could no doubt make it worth both ways.

Comment: and no-one built the shop of theseus @curiousdannii so no, i don't see your point. i think the world would have to be deterministic, at least, if both deaths are to occur at the same time

Comment: @another_stack Who requires that "both" deaths happen at the same time? The machinery could easily kill you slightly afterwards as punishment for failing to live in the simulation. Your question needs to account for every situation, even ones as bizarre as that.